# How convert txt file to UTF-8 from Windows-1251?

Tags: character-encoding

Windows 10, Emacs 25.

When I want to convert file from Windows-1251 to UTF-8 I use Notepad++.

Before convert:

[image]

convert:

[image]

after convert:

[image]

My question is: Is it possible this convert in Emacs?

Answer (score 11):

One should use the command `set-buffer-file-coding-system` (`C-x RET f`), set the encoding, and then save the file.

Note that you may want to first `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` (`C-x RET r`) before performing the above step, if the file is opened with the wrong encoding in the first place.

Comment: This worked for me. It modified the buffer and I was able to save as UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is to:

1. Type <kbd>C-x RET c</kbd>
2. Select the desired coding system (in this case probably `utf-8-dos`)
3. Pass <kbd>C-x C-w</kbd> as the command and pass the name of the file to write

Comment: Not help.  File stay on "windows-1251"

Comment: @Alex sorry, I thought it was the other way around. I edited the answer to work for this case.

Comment: I try again, but it not help. Coding system not change to utf-8-dos

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

1. Visit the file with <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>.
2. Revert opened buffer to the original file encoding (`cp-1251` in
   this case) with <kbd>M-x</kbd> + `revert-buffer-wth-coding-system`.
3. Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> + `set-buffer-file-coding-system` to set encoding to utf-8.
4. Save the file.

Comment: this answer is similar to @xji 's answer.